# How to connect to remote docker instance using virtual private network

Tags: docker

I have a docker instance on a host which has two network interfaces, one attached to the internet and one virtual private network.

The host is able to connect to the internet and the VPN.

The docker instance running on the host can connect to the internet, but cannot reach the VPN.

How can I assure my docker instance can connect to the VPN?

I have read explanation about using pipework (https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework/) but don't see how I can get this to work for me.

I am using docker 0.8.0 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you do not need **pipework**. In default configuration, you should be able to reach both host interfaces from docker eth0 interface. Possible problems:

- DNS: my default container resolv.conf is 8.8.8.8 and it may not know some VPN-specific domain names.
- Filtering/firewall at host possibly drops/does not forward packets to VPN. (check firewall f.e ufw status, ...)
- You can check IP ranges for possible conflicts in docker networking. In case of conflict, you can configure [docker network interface docker0 manually](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/) to be ok with your VPN:

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto docker0
iface docker0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.1         <--- configure this
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_fd 0
```

Comment: I am not using DNS, just direct IP address.
/etc/network/interfaces contains:

    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

which makes me wonder how it can reach the internet at all

Comment: ad /etc/network/interfaces - Ubuntu uses NetworkManager and it's configuration is not stored in this file. (try  `nmcli d` to print interfaces, or `ifconfig` of course).